# Snap guides to ruler markings

Tags: gimp

When adding or moving a guide in GIMP, how do I make it snap to a ruler position?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that you want to "snap" the guide to an exact or even position like exactly 1000 px or 1".

I don't know of a way to do that but I have found that when setting guides it is so fast to zoom in to a fairly tight resolution with the CTRL-ScrollWheel combination then use the status area at the bottom to set it exactly where I want it, that snapping has never been something I looked for.

The main reason for zooming is just to give the mouse finer control if you are looking for an individual pixel. And since the tool changes to move, once you drag a guide on it is pretty quick even if you start at a fairly low display resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a horizontal ruler from a point in the ruler by pressing `Ctrl` or a vertical ruler by pressing `Alt` on the point.

E.g. say we have the following ruler:

[image: sample image with ruler]

By pressing `Ctrl` on the bottom point of the ruler, we'd get a horizontal guide:

[image: horizontal guide]

By pressing `Alt` we'd get a vertical guide:

[image: vertical guide]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Snap to a ruler position? Rulers are on the top/left of the canvas, dragging a guide onto the ruler removes the guide. Can you explain a bit better what you want to do?

Edit: Just mentioning here that you can create a ruler/guide by [specifying a percentage](http://docs.gimp.org/nl/script-fu-guide-new-percent.html), but still it's no snapping.

You can also configure a grid (Image -> configure grid) and show it (view -> show grid) to make placing guides at regular intervals a little easier.

Comment: I want to drag a guide onto the drawing area and make it fall exactly at the nearest ruler position. This is possible using Photoshop. See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-74c4a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-74c1a

"Align the guide with the ruler ticks by holding down Shift as you drag the guide."

(By the way, the downvote was not mine. Still, your response is more suited as a comment than an answer.)

Comment: Ah I see now, by bad. Dennis explains what I do, zoom in tight and eyeball to position the rule. There's no snapping of rulers 'every x units', but pixel-by-pixel.